# Mock carbon now and make code a little more clean

Tags: laravel, unit-testing

I want to reduce if else statements and write unit testing for the case holiday. I want to mock and use `shouldReceive('isHoliday')` but I don't know.

```
if ($request->isVip == 1) {
    $fee = 0;
} else {
    if (in_array($now->format('l'), ['Saturday','Sunday']) || $now->isHoliday()) {
        $fee = 110;
    } else {
        $fee = $now->gte(Carbon::parse('8:45')) && $now->lt(Carbon::parse('18:00')) ? 0 : 110;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For ease of testing, creating a logic class to handle your fee logic, is an easy way to unit test it later. Which also makes it possible to use early returns, which makes the if / else statements more readable. My rewrite is this.

```
class FeeService
{
    public function fee(bool $isVip)
    {
        if ($isVip) {
            return 0;
        }

        $now = now();

        if ($today->dayOfWeek == Carbon::SATURDAY || $today->dayOfWeek == Carbon::SUNDAY || $now->isHoliday()) {
            return 110;
        }

        if ($now->gte(Carbon::parse('8:45')) && $now->lt(Carbon::parse('18:00'))) {
            return 0;
        }

        return 110;
    }
}
```

Come to testing, `Carbon` has logic to mock dates, that is by far the easiest way to test logic based on different date outcomes of `now()`. You can also use this in a feature test, but as the question is formulated, i feel this is the easiest way to achieve what you want.

```
use Tests\TestCase;

class FeeServiceTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testFeeService()
    {
        Carbon::setTestNow(Carbon::create(2022, 12, 25, 18, 0);
        $feeService = new FeeService();

        $this->assertEquals(110, $feeService->fee(false));
    }

    public function testFeeService()
    {
        Carbon::setTestNow(Carbon::create(2022, 12, 23, 18, 0);
        $feeService = new FeeService();

        $this->assertEquals(0, $feeService->fee(false));
    }
}
```